# Log.w() throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` despite `@PrepareForTest(Log.class)`

Tags: android, junit, powermock

I am trying to write a JUnit (5) for a class that indirectly uses `Log.w()`.

When I first encountered `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` as a result, I quickly found out that this is a well known issue in Android development and that I can either use mocking:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Log.class)
class mySusuManager {
...
}
```

with the following `dependencies {}` in my app's [build.gradle](https://proandroiddev.com/testing-on-android-using-junit-5-61b3d2cb3198):

```
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.1"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.1"
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1"
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.1"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'                         
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:4.5.1"             
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.9"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.9"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9"
```

**or** use a gradle flag:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

I tried **both** (not simultaneously), but I am still getting the dreaded:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe" ...

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

    at android.util.Log.w(Log.java:37)
    ...
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Use Roboelctric.

Comment: @JaySouper Thanks. I first need to understand why those two highly popular and documented techniques work for others but not for me. For example, I just discovered that `testImplementation` produces an import error in the test class, whereas `implementation` doesn't. I could not find an explanation for that, either.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of all, I am posting here how I solved my issue, **indirectly**.

Most existing SO references to this `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` issue seem to referring to versions of the tools and libraries that are older than what is available today.

So, thanks to the article [How to mock static methods with Mockito](https://frontbackend.com/java/how-to-mock-static-methods-with-mockito), I discovered that with the introduction of Mockito 3.x, I do not need PowerMock to mock the `android.util.Log` class.

Here is how I accomplished this:

**Step 1**: I removed the

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Log.class)
```

above my `mySusuManagerTest` class definition.

**Step 2**: I replaced all powermock imports with a single:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
```

**Step 3**: In `build.gradle` I replaced all `testImplementation "org.powermock` occurrences and the `testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-core` one, with a single `mockito-inline` class reference.

```
implementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.11.0"
```

**Step 4**: Inside the test method, I only placed a single `mockStatic` line:

```
@Test
void thisIsTheMethodImTesting() {
    Mockito.mockStatic(Log.class);
    // test + assert code here    
}
```